# How to get unique value in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in which I have some products and from them I want to get just unique values. I have a database in which I have values like `Kia Picanto, Toyota Corolla, Kia Sportage, BMW Series 6, BMW Series 7` etc. Now I want to show values like `Kia, Toyota, BMW`. I am trying to search over the internet but didn't find any possible solutions so that's why I ma posting my question here to get the solution.I am using

SQL:

```
$sql = $db_con->prepare("SELECT `post_title` FROM `panel_product` WHERE `product_type` LIKE '%vehicle%' ORDER BY `post_title`");
$sql->execute();
$menufectures = $sql->fetchAll();
if (count($menufectures) > 0) {
    foreach ($menufectures as $key) {
        $brand = explode(' ', $key['post_title']);
        $brand = $brand[0];
        echo $brand.'<br />';
    }
}
```

But I am getting `Kia, Kia, Toyota, BMW, BMW`. Please let me know if you have any solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the ones you've displayed in an array that you can check while iterating:

```
// Initialize a new variable
$brands = [];

foreach ($menufectures as $key) {
    $brand = explode(' ', $key['post_title']);
    $brand = $brand[0];

    if (!isset($brands[$brand])) {
        // It doesn't exist in the array so echo it and add it to the array
        $brands[$brand] = true;
        echo $brand.'<br />';
    }
}
```